# Efficiency of code for organizing values from a database

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I have to put my database's data in this format (values will differ, obviously), I think it's called an associative array (I'm horrible with terminology).

```
$values=array(
            "Jan" => 110,
            "Feb" => 130,
            "Mar" => 215,
            "Apr" => 81,
            "May" => 310,
            "Jun" => 110,
            "Jul" => 190,
            "Aug" => 175,
            "Sep" => 390,
            "Oct" => 286,
            "Nov" => 150,
            "Dec" => 196
    );
```

Here's what I developed:

```
    $sql = "SELECT MONTH(AddDate) AS Date, column_name FROM table ORDER BY AddDate ASC";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $prev_date = null;

$values=array();

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res) ) {
    if ( $row['Date'] != $prev_date) {
        $month = $row['Date'];
        $sql = "SELECT count(MONTH(AddDate)) AS EntryAmount FROM `table` WHERE MONTH(AddDate)=$month ";
        $countResults = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        if( $entryAmount = mysql_fetch_array($countResults) ) {
            $values[$row['Date']] =  $entryAmount['EntryAmount'];
        }
        $prev_date = $row['Date'];
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Array ( [9] => 999 [10] => 986 [11] => 264 )
```

Comment: Be a bit more descriptive about what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do all of this in a single query:

```
select month(AddDate) as theMonth,
       count(*) as numberOfRows
from   `table`
group by theMonth
order by theMonth
```

Then the outer loop goes away and the inner loop becomes:

```
if( $row = mysql_fetch_array($results) ) 
{
    $values[$row['theMonth']] = $row['numberOfRows'];
}
```

It should perform noticeably better for moderately sized data sets.  Do note, however, that by using the `month` function, you lose any benefit of indexes that you might otherwise be able to use.

Comment: Ahh, I get it now. Now I understand how to use sql better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

using a GROUP BY (not tested):

```
$sql = "SELECT MONTH(AddDate) AS Date, count(AddDate) AS EntryAmount FROM table ORDER BY AddDate ASC GROUP BY MONTH(AddDate)";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$values=array();

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res) ) {
    $values[$row['Date']] =  $row['EntryAmount'];
}
```